# How to determine the type without instantiating the object?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**in java**

```
public class GenericUtil<T> {

    public boolean judge(){
        return T instanceof Application;
    }
}
```

**in kotlin**

```
class GenericUtil<T> {
    fun judge(): Boolean {
        return T is Application
    }
}
```

I just want to determine if the generic T is an object type...

Comment: I am afraid that's not possible due to type erasure. But you can retain the generics information by using an extra `TypeReference` class, which retains generic information. Checkout Spring `ParameterizedTypeReference` or Rest assured's `TypeRef`. Maybe that helps. Otherwise you will need extra Class<T> parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, however, you can use reflection:

```
public class GenericUtil<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    
    public GenericUtil(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public boolean judge(){
        return Application.classisAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```